# iTextSharp Table last cell fixed height not working

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to generate a PDF document. I have a slight issue with the last cell in a nested table, it some how has a height which is a remainder of the cell space, even though I have set a fixed height for each cell. Is there a way to override this behavior so it stays as a fixed height. I have attached an image of what is happening.

```
var cats = DAL.Merchandise.GetListOfMerchandiseCategories();
var data = DAL.Merchandise.GetListOfMerchandise().AsQueryable();

var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25);

var output = new MemoryStream();
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
var mainTable = new PdfPTable(3);

    mainTable.SetWidths(new float[] { 200f, 200f, 200f });
    mainTable.TotalWidth = 600f;
    mainTable.LockedWidth = true;

    float[] widths = new float[] { 60f, 120f };

    var items = data.Where(x => x.Category == cat);
    var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(_ => _.PartDesc).Select(_ => new { _.Key, items = _ });

    foreach(var item in groupedItems) {
        var table = new PdfPTable(2);

        table.TotalWidth = widths.Sum();
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.SetWidths(widths);

        //Spacer
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("")) { Colspan = 2, FixedHeight = 30, Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER });

        Image jpg;
        //try
        //{
        //      jpg = Image.GetInstance(string.Format(GlobalClass.ImageManagerURLForImages.ToString(),items.ImageName));
        //}
        //catch
        //{
            jpg = Image.GetInstance(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/_common/img/noimageavailable.png"));
        //}

        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(jpg, true) { Colspan = 2, Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER });

        //PartDesc
        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item.items.First().PartDesc, subTitleFont)) { Colspan = 2, FixedHeight = 20, Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER });

        var alternate = false;
        foreach(var part in item.items) {
            var color = alternate ? BaseColor.GRAY : BaseColor.WHITE;
            table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(part.PartData) ? "" : part.PartData)) { Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER, BackgroundColor = color, MinimumHeight = 15f, FixedHeight = 15f, PaddingBottom = 1, PaddingTop = 1, PaddingLeft = 2 });
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(part.Price))
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(part.PartNo)) { Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER, BackgroundColor = color, MinimumHeight = 15f, FixedHeight = 15f, PaddingBottom = 1, PaddingTop = 1, PaddingLeft = 2 });
            else
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(string.Format("{0} £{1:0.00}pp", part.PartNo, part.Price))) { Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER, MinimumHeight = 15f, BackgroundColor = color, FixedHeight = 15f, PaddingBottom = 1, PaddingTop = 1, PaddingLeft = 2 });

            alternate = !alternate;
        }

        table.SetExtendLastRow(false, false);

        mainTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(table) { Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER });
    }

    //To fill in the blank cells on a row, so that the row can get displayed
    var count = groupedItems.Count();
    while (count > 3)
        count -= 3;

    var remainder = 3 - count;

    for(int i = 0; i < remainder; i++) {
        mainTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("")) { Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER });
    }

    document.Add(mainTable);
```

Snippet from the Generated PDF
[image: Snippet from Generated PDF]

**EDIT**

*Since we don't have access to the DAL the code above has been re-worked below to use a mock class*

```
public class item {
    public String PartDesc;
    public String PartData;
    public String PartNo;
    public String Price;
    public item(String desc, String data, String no, String price) {
        this.PartDesc = desc;
        this.PartData = data;
        this.PartNo = no;
        this.Price = price;
    }
}
```

And the actual code:

```
//Sample data since we don't have the DAL
var items = new item[] {
    new item("Alpha", "A Data", "A", "1"),
    new item("Alpha", "B Data", "B", "2"),
    new item("Bravo", "A Data", "A", "1"),
    new item("Bravo", "B Data", "B", "2"),
    new item("Charlie", "A Data", "A", "1"),
    new item("Charlie", "B Data", "B", "2"),
    new item("Charlie", "C Data", "C", "3"),
    new item("Charlie", "D Data", "D", "4"),
    new item("Charlie", "E Data", "E", "5")
};

//File to output to
var outputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");

//Will hold the PDF as a byte array when we're done
Byte[] bytes;


using (var output = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25)) {
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output)) {
            document.Open();

            var mainTable = new PdfPTable(3);


            mainTable.SetWidths(new float[] { 200f, 200f, 200f });
            mainTable.TotalWidth = 600f;
            mainTable.LockedWidth = true;

            float[] widths = new float[] { 60f, 120f };

            var groupedItems = items.GroupBy(_ => _.PartDesc).Select(_ => new { _.Key, items = _ });

            foreach (var item in groupedItems) {
                var table = new PdfPTable(2);

                table.TotalWidth = widths.Sum();
                table.LockedWidth = true;
                table.SetWidths(widths);

                //Spacer
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("")) { Colspan = 2, FixedHeight = 30, Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER });


                //PartDesc
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item.items.First().PartDesc)) { Colspan = 2, FixedHeight = 20, Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER });

                var alternate = false;
                foreach (var part in item.items) {
                    var color = alternate ? BaseColor.GRAY : BaseColor.WHITE;
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(part.PartData) ? "" : part.PartData)) { Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER, BackgroundColor = color, MinimumHeight = 15f, FixedHeight = 15f, PaddingBottom = 1, PaddingTop = 1, PaddingLeft = 2 });
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(part.Price))
                        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(part.PartNo)) { Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER, BackgroundColor = color, MinimumHeight = 15f, FixedHeight = 15f, PaddingBottom = 1, PaddingTop = 1, PaddingLeft = 2 });
                    else
                        table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(string.Format("{0} £{1:0.00}pp", part.PartNo, part.Price))) { Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER, MinimumHeight = 15f, BackgroundColor = color, FixedHeight = 15f, PaddingBottom = 1, PaddingTop = 1, PaddingLeft = 2 });

                    alternate = !alternate;
                }

                table.SetExtendLastRow(false, false);

                mainTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(table) { Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER });
            }

            //To fill in the blank cells on a row, so that the row can get displayed
            var count = groupedItems.Count();
            while (count > 3)
                count -= 3;

            var remainder = 3 - count;

            for (int i = 0; i < remainder; i++) {
                mainTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("")) { Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER });
            }

            document.Add(mainTable);

            document.Close();
        }
    }
    bytes = output.ToArray();
}


System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(outputFile, bytes);
```

Comment: We don't have your DAL so it can be a little confusing trying to walk through your code since we can't actually run it. I've updated your post to include a mock class and mock data that still simulates your problem. I don't have a solution but hopefully this will help someone else troubleshoot better.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Hey @Valeklosse did you ever find a solution for this? I have same problem as you described above and can't find a solution. Thx

Comment: @Borbea Unfortunately we never did come to a solution in the end, and I think another developer ended up rewriting it using a different library, I believe it was aspPDF

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with the following setting:

table.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
table.setExtendLastRow(false, false);

The alignment part is the most important one, because with default alignment the row extension value gets overwritten on rendering.